# Why is this the Time Complexity of this For Loop O(N)?

Tags: java, algorithm, time-complexity

Is there a way to understand why the time complexity of the following is O(N), either(or both) from intuition or by proof?

What it does is basically that given the input of an integer `array`, we are creating the `firstSmallLeft` array of the same length where `firstSmallLeft[i]` = the first index where `array[index]` < `array[i]` when doing the **back scan**. (i.e., for index i, it scans from i-1, ... , j until it finds the first smaller element such that array[j] < array[i])

For Example, if input = `[3,2,5,6,4,1]`.
firstSmallLeft would be `[-1,-1,1,2,1,-1]`

```
//input int[] array
int[] firstSmallLeft = new int[array.length];
firstSmallLeft[0] = -1;
for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i ++){
    int cur = i -1;
    while (cur >=0 && array[cur] >= array[i]){
        cur = firstSmallLeft[cur];
    }

    firstSmallLeft[i] = cur;
}
```

Comment: How did you confirm it was an `O(n)` runtime / what makes you think it is? Without digging too far into analyzing it, my first reaction is that it isn't.

Comment: Can you explain the logic behind the `while` loop?

Comment: If I am right, firstSmallLeft would be `[-1,-1,1,1,1,-1]`.

Comment: @ScottHunter ,        using a simple example input [1, 10, 9, 5,3], the output would be [-1,0,0,0, x]. When we are at the index 4 (element 3), it looks back at index 3 which is element 5. We check the firstSmallLeft index of element 5 by checking firstSmallLeft[3] , which gives us 0. Then we skipped checking 5, 9, 10...., and jumped to element at index 0. array[0] = 1, 1 < 3, we terminated the back scan process. The idea is that since 5 > 3 , firstSmallLeft of element 5 is guaranteed to be larger than firstSmallLeft of 3. We can skip a bunch of unnecessary elements.

Comment: @YvesDaoust, the result should be the  FIRST element thats smaller than the current one when doing a back scan (from right to left).  so for index 3 , array[3] = 6, the first element smaller than 6 is 5 which is at index 2, so firstSmallLeft[3] should be 2 instead of 1.

Comment: Is there *ever* a circumstance where the body of the  `while` loop would be executed more than once?

Comment: Ok, I understand now.

Comment: @ScottHunter , yes.   consider this one [1,5,10, 8, 3] , before the last element, the output firstSmallLeft would be [-1,0,1,1, X] . we are now checking index = 4, which is element 3, i = 4, cur = 3.   array[3] = 8 > array[4] = 3, so we do a backscan. cur = firstSmallLeft[cur] = firstSmallLeft[3] = 1, thus cur = 1.  but array[1] = 5 still > array[i] = 3, we enters the next execution. cur = firstSmallLeft[1] = 0, now we get 1, 1 < 3. we stopped there. thus firstSmallLeft[4] = 0.

Comment: @ScottHunter: with (2, 4, 3, 6, 5, 8, 7, 1), the number of executions (evaluations) of the while are 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 5, for a total of 15.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An important insight is that the last entry in `firstSmallLeft` that received a value (at index `i-1`) represents the **top of a stack**, which is implemented as a linked list. An entry in `firstSmallLeft` represents an input value (as the index where it occurs is the index in the input `array`) and a link in the linked list (as its value is an index in `firstSmallLeft`). The bottom element in the stack has a null-link (-1).

In general not all elements in `firstSmallLeft` are in the represented stack, since some indices are skipped over. An example:

Let's say that the top of the stack is at index 100 (when `i` is 101), and it has as value 40, and `firstSmallLeft[40]` is -1, then that means we have a stack with just two elements (`array[100]` and `array[40]`), and none of the other indices in `firstSmallLeft` are included in the current stack. Each one of those once *was* on the stack, but have since been popped of the stack.

Every time `cur = firstSmallLeft[cur];` is executed (in the inner loop), we actually pop an element of the stack (the linked list that starts at `cur` is one element shorter).

And when we do `firstSmallLeft[i] = cur` we push `array[i]` on the stack, making a reference to the part of the stack we wanted to keep.

Now this "virtual" stack is identified, we see the following:

A value is pushed exactly **once** on the stack, and can only be popped **once** from the stack, after which it is never visited again.

The overhead of evaluating the `while` expression once more to find that we need to exit the loop, occurs as many times as the outer loop iterates (i.e. `n-1` times)

Therefore the algorithm is O(n).

Comment: That's not true. for the example you provided, it will immediately stopped at each element's immediately left element. i.e. the output would be [-1,0,...,n-2]. So the time complexity for this case is O(n-1) = O(n)

Comment: Why upvotes for a post that is proven wrong ?

Comment: Is not ... , 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and examply where the backscan goes entirely back, yielding -1 for all. Just a small mistake of @trincot.

Comment: @JoopEggen By exhaustive tests on all permutations of a list up to 12 elements, I confirm that the worst-case number of executions of the while loop is consistently 2n-1.

Comment: @JoopEggen, thanks, do you have ideas on the proof or intuition. Btw, where can we do the exhaustive test?

Comment: I fixed my answer. Joop is right. I think we can now see this is O(n²), right?

Comment: Sorry, after reading the code thoroughly, instead of seeing that the test data is cumbersome, `cur = firstSmallLeft[cur];` skips back. So O(N) might still be the case.

Comment: Completely rewrote this answer. The previous version was admittedly completely wrong, as discussed above.

Answer (score 0):

You can imagine this algorithm as creating a collection of chains of elements. For each element in the array, following the chain backwards will take you to smaller and smaller values until you walk off the array.

To build the chain for the next element of the array, we start by looking at the chain of the element before us. We’ll then follow that chain for some number of steps, then form the chain for the new element by adding a link back to the place we stopped.

The key intuition here is that ***the length of the chains drops quickly and grows slowly***. More concretely, let C be the length of the chain that starts from the current element of the array. We begin with C = 0. At each step in the algorithm, we drop C by some amount, then increment C by at most one. This means that across all n iterations of the algorithm, C increases at most n times. Therefore, since C is never negative, C can decrease at most n times. And therefore the total work spent in the inner while loop decreasing C, across all iterations of the algorithm, is O(n).

(If you’re familiar with amortized analyses and potential functions, you can also think of this as setting Φ = C.)

This same sort of argument arises in a number of other algorithms, such as building a Cartesian tree with a stack and constructing the failure table in the Knuth-Morris-Pratt string matching algorithm.

Comment: isn't the length of  chain growing quickly, for example, element i could form a chain all the way to index 0. Or I have misunderstood the analogy of chain ?

Comment: You can form a chain all the way back to index zero, yes. So let’s say you do that. What happens with the next element? One option is that it’s bigger than the element before it. In that case, the while loop does no work and the chain gets longer. Or perhaps the next element is the smallest. Then we walk all the way back to the start of the chain, but then we write a -1 in the array slot and the new chain has length zero. That means future operations will run faster because the chain is now short. Or it could be something in between.